# Regular Expression For URL Query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I've been using mod_rewrite in my htaccess file to rewrite my urls and I've run into a problem when doing pagination.

Here's the url for my page:
http://domain.com/concerts/features/folk-roots?page=2

htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^features/([^/]*)?page=([0-9]*)$ featureCat.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

It works fine without the page query, but if I want to change pages I can't figure out how to write the regular expression to grab the page #.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use RewriteCond immediately before the RewriteRule to get access to the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^features/([^/]*)$ featureCat.php?cat=$1&page=%1 [NC,L]
```