# Regular Expression for URL Rewriting

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I found a Question similar to my problem([Regular Expression For URL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242410/regular-expression-for-url-query)) but could not make my problem to be resolved.

So I am having trouble with Regular Expressions in HTACCESS.

So what I have in my website is :

**ROOT : (my web root is in a sub folder 'sites')**

/sites/index.php and other files

/sites/sites/**sample_folder_name**/

Now what I would like to do is to ReWrite URL :

/sites/sites/**sample_folder_name/file_name.php**

to :

/sites/**file_name.php**?siteredirect=**sample_folder_name**

Remember :
If the URL contains any Request Parameters, then those must also be rewrited, i.e :

Example :

/sites/sites/**sample_folder_name/file_name.php**?cat_id=1&user=2

to :

/sites/**file_name.php**?cat_id=1&user=2&siteredirect=**sample_folder_name**

The parameters are supposed to be unknown instead of user and cat_id. It could be any parameters. Means that whatever is written after .php should also come in URL.

Means :

/sites/sites/**sample_folder_name/file_name.php**?if_any_parameters

then :

/sites/**file_name.php**?if_any_parameters&siteredirect=**sample_folder_name**

otherwise :

/sites/**file_name.php**?siteredirect=**sample_folder_name**

Currently, the rewrite is working great but I am not able to make them work with parameters.

What I have in my HTACCESS right now :

```
RewriteRule ^sites\/([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\/([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\.php(.*)$ $2.php(?(?=$3)$3&)siteredirect=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sites\/([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\/$ index.php?siteredirect=$1 [L]
```

After this, it is giving me a 404.

Please Help... Where am I doing it wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `QSA` flag (Query String Append):

```
RewriteRule ^sites(/sites/[^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1?siteredirect=$2 [QSA]
```

What's more, invert your rules: you won't have to use `L`

Also, consider using `<Location>` directives, it will make your job easier:

```
<Location "/site/site">
    #rules here
</Location>

<LocationMatch "^/site/(?!site/)">
    #rules here
</Location>
```